# Allow Github Organization to read repository

Tags: git, github

I have created a repository inside an Organization, and want to give all members of that organization access to read/fork the repository without making it public.

Is that possible?

I know we could add all members manually to a team called "All members" and then give that team access. But the organization is large, with people quitting and starting all the time. I don't want to have to remember adding/removing people from this group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this answer is a little late but you can actually do that by adjusting the default repository permission.

1. Go to your organisation on GitHub
2. Move to `"Member privileges"`
3. Select your wanted option `"Read"` in "Default repository permission"

> Note that this will apply to all of the repositories the organisation ownes. Also note that this rule only is applicable for members of the organisation and not for outside collaborators.