# Allow all organization members to read repository without changing default access

Tags: github

I want to allow all members of a GitHub organization read access **only** to a certain repository.

If I change the default access (like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44149532/2375105)), it changes it for all repositories.

Is it possible?